# Why this exclusion not working for long sentences?

Tags: text-processing, perl

Command

```
perl -ne 'print unless /.[240,]/' input.txt > output.txt
```

which includes some sentences which are longer than 240 letters. Why?

Example data

> Development of World Funny Society program on young people who
>   are working hard for the sport and social life such that they have
>   time to go pizzeria every now and then and do some fun, programming
>   and having great breakfast:| World scenario of free time programs are
>   often too long such that this star probably makes the program upset
>   (*)|Again a very long option which is not probably the reason which
>   makes this program upset|good shorter option which is ok but nice to
>   write here coffee morning messages|c last option is always good one
>   because you know that you can soon stop   1

Example data 2

> Indications of this program depends on many things and I like much
>   more this than Lorem ipsum which is too generic and takes too much
>   time to open:|short option just in case|little longer option so good
>   to have it here too|shorter which is better too but how much is the
>   question|shortest is not the least|longer one once again but not too
>   long  1

Comment: This question should have been closed, not voted up, because the OP's problem is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax: `[]` is used to match a character class, while here you're trying to match a number of occurences of `.`, which can be done using `{}`:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /.{240,}/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Also, as suggested by salva in the comments, the pattern can be shortened to `.{240}`:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /.{240}/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: And then, it can be simplified further: `perl -ne 'print unless /.{240}/' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @salva That would print every line but those containing exactly 240 characters.

Comment: no, my one-liner prints any line containing less that 240 characters. In order to match lines of 240 chars you would have to use `/^.{240}$/`.